# Inseting data from gridview into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to insert this data into a SQL Server table but it's failing. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
Private Sub Save_LifeAssureds()
    If DbConn.sqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then 
         DbConn.sqlCon.Open()

    Try
        For i = 0 To dgvDisplayAussuredLives.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim row1 As String = dgvDisplayAussuredLives.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            Dim row2 As String = dgvDisplayAussuredLives.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString
            Dim row3 As String = dgvDisplayAussuredLives.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
            Dim row4 As Date = dgvDisplayAussuredLives.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString
            Dim row5 As String = dgvDisplayAussuredLives.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString
            Dim row6 As String = dgvDisplayAussuredLives.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString

            DbConn.sqlCmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tb_HCPLivess (PolicyNumber, surname, Othernames, NRCBen, Gender, Birthdate, Benefits, Relationship, ClientNRC, Status, ProductSymbol) " & _
               "VALUES('" & txtPolicyNumber.Text & "','" & row1 & "','" & row2 & "','" & Format(row4, "yyyy/MM/dd") & "'," & row5 & ",'" & row6 & "', '" & txtNrcPh.Text & "','Active',bsh')")

            DbConn.sqlCmd.Connection = DbConn.sqlCon

            DbConn.sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'data_adapter.Update(m_Dataset)
            Debug.WriteLine(DbConn.sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery())

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
    DbConn.sqlCon.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, use sql parameters for you insert statement.  Just plain makes everything about it easy compared to concatenating strings to construct the statement

Comment: Firstly, a `DataGridView` is a `DataGridView`. A `GridView` is something else. As for inserting data, don't do it row by row like that. Create a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid, then use a `SqlDataAdapter` with an appropriate `InsertCommand` to save all the data in one go. Post #3 [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) provides an example.